# Why does a null reference in OrderBy not blow up?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I came across the following code:

```
    foreach( var member in manager.Memberships.Where( mem => someBooleanExpression )
                          .OrderBy( mem => mem.Person.LName ).ToList() ) {
                if( member.Person == null )
                    continue;
                addListItemToAllDropDowns( member.Person.FullName, member.PersonID.ToString() );
            }
```

Actually I added the "continue;" line myself to illustrate what was going on. It actually hits that line. I don't understand how this is possible.

To get into the loop, it would have had to order the collection based on member.Person. But member.Person is null for at least one element, so how is it possible it did not blow up? I added .ToList() to the end of the OrderBy to remove the possibility of deferred confusion, but that couldn't have been the problem since it would need to have realized the OrderBy prior to getting into the loop.

I'm not aware of any special exception handling in OrderBy. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out before I hit Post but I'll document it here. The reason is because manager.Memberships is an expression that is getting converted to T-SQL. If it were an in-memory collection, my expectation would have been right. Since it's an expression, it has some lost-in-translation effects as it gets converted into T-SQL, which does not care if Person is null or not. Leaky abstraction.

Comment: It has to work like that or you wouldn't be able to work with most sql data. Any nullable column would become unusable.